# Limit php curl requests per sec for getting all links on the site page

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to get all links at concrete web-page. I need only 'a' tags with concrete parameter. But firstly, as far as I know, I have to download the whole page.

I use this (mostly not mine) code:

```
<?php
function file_get_contents_curl($url) 
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); //Устанавливаем параметр, чтобы curl возвращал данные, вместо того, чтобы выводить их в браузер.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, true);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}
$startUrl = 'address';
$data = file_get_contents_curl($startUrl);
echo($data);
?>
```

By this I'm getting error "Too many requests". The question is: can I change the amount of requests for finging elements of links array?
I think about curl_multi, but as far as I understand, it assumes that I already have the array and only need to make multiple threads.

Help, please.

Comment: a request is a request. doesn't matter what you're doing with the fetched data, it was still an http request. if you're getting blocked for sending too many too fast, then SLOW DOWN. put a sleep() in there or something.

Comment: Ok, sleep. But I only use one function. Where I should use the sleep? Make an example for it, please.

Comment: This code performs only one request. If you are calling this in a loop, maybe a sleep could help you. But, if your code is this, the problem is on the other server side

Comment: My code is this exactly. Except the link, of course. And there is no visible way to solve the problem?

Comment: @KOHTPOJIEP, how many visitors do you have? It might be because of too many requests for this page you have. Then, you need to find some other solutions like caching, or even singleton pattern. It depends on how your project works and how often you receive different response for your calls

Comment: The site is not mine and it surely stands the normal load (I don't know how big the "normal" load should be, but the site is a huge info-portal). I'm just trying to make simple parses-script. I don't want high speed, so slow solutions will be acceptable. But all I can do with this is in the parser code.

Comment: I think if your data doesn't change immediately, cache solution would be the best for you

Comment: I know what the cache is, but didn't see any things manipulating it. Can you give a link, please? May be in the answer even, not in the comments.

Comment: google it. Maybe this could help: http://www.xeweb.net/2010/01/15/simple-php-caching/